# Alamofire Encoding issue with struct

Tags: swift, alamofire

I have a rather complex structure to encode in order to pass it with the body of my post.

```
case .sendData(let parameters):
    urlRequest = try Alamofire.JSONEncoding.default.encode(urlRequest, withJSONObject: parameters.encode())
```

parameters is not of the [String:Any] type, but of the type 'QuestionnaireAnswers' which is a struct. So I need to create the encode functions. I tried the code below but it fails

```
struct ItemResponse {
    let question: String
    let answerArray: [String]
}

// MARK: Encodable
extension ItemResponse {
    func encode() -> [String: Any] {
        return [
            "question": question,
            "answerArray": answerArray
        ]
    }
}

struct QuestionnaireAnswers{
    let version: Int
    var answers: [ItemResponse]
}


// MARK: Encodable
extension QuestionnaireAnswers {
    func encode() -> [String: Any] {
        return [
            "version": version,
            "answers": answers
        ]
    }
}
```

In the end, the JSON should look like this :

```
{
    version: 1,
    answers: [
      { question: 'dog', answerArray: ['yay'] },
      { question: 'cat', answerArray: ['< 500'] },
      { question: 'tree', answerArray: ['sorry', 'OK then','NotWorking'] },
    ],
  }
```